# How to get battery percentage based the timestamp in android?

Tags: java, android, mobile, battery, batterymanager

How to get battery percentage based the timestamp in android?
Is that possible to get the battery percentage based on the date timestamps?

I'm trying to get the battery percentage based the time which I have spent time on the apps.
In Android/Java Code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get battery percentage by timestamp, battery consumption depends on various factors. [Here's](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring) how you can monitor the current battery level.